# Maven create jar from xsd

Tags: java, xsd, maven-3, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

I have to create a maven project in such way that it picks given xsd paths,create classes and packages all of them in a jar.xjc plugin just creates classes but doesnt package them.Please help

Comment: Do you use `<packaging>jar</packaging>` ? Anyway could you add your pom.xml?

Answer (score 2):

Create one maven module for generate the jar file from xsd

1. Define the pom like below:(note:packaging is jar)

   ```
      <groupId>com.your.company.xsd</groupId>
       <artifactId>GenerateXSD</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>
   ```
2. Add jaxb plugin

---

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-abc-data</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xjc</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/resources/abc/abc.xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/abc</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```